# How to maintain version for maven dependency?

Tags: java, maven

I have below spring boot module and all are devcelop in maven.

1. common
2. service
3. registration
4. report
5. transaction

All are independent project. Only common module is having some common features and its included as a jar in other module.

Now all the module they are using maven dependency and spring boot also they are used few common jar files. So I need to maintain all jar version in all module.

So is there any work around for maintain version in some common place???

for example below dependency I have used in all module

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have to maintain this in all pom file. If try to upgrade version then I need to do this change in all file.

But If we get this from single file then I just need to do this in sigle place and reflect in all place.

Please give some idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<dependencyManagement>` to retain the same version of the artifact in all child poms. This way you mention a version only in one place.

// parent pom:

```
<dependencyManagement>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
           <version>2.3.1</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

// child pom:

```
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: In my case there is no such case like parent or child. All are individual module

Comment: Then write a parent POM that is used in these projects. Or this a reason not to do this?

Comment: Writing a parent pom is not possible... Those r individual module.. can we use properties file